# FirebaserecyclerAdapter doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get the following error when building gradle. I don't know what to do please guys help me but this problem came after updating studio from 2.3 to 3.0.1 early was working fine but now it fails.

I used studio 2.3 no error detected but after updating this error appears. When I synchronized the project no error was detected in any dependencies but when I went to run/build the following error appears:

Constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions
found: Class,int,Class,DatabaseReference
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T,VH are type-variables:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
        VH extends ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
        Error:(74, 11) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBindViewHolder(InstaViewHolder,int,Insta) in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
Error:(81, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

My main activity.java code is the following:

```
package com.example.dunia_technology.suaforum;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private RecyclerView mInstaList;
        private DatabaseReference  mDatabase;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            mInstaList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.insta_list);
            mInstaList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mInstaList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("InstaApp");

            mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mAuthListener =new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
                        Intent loginIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);

                    }
                }
            };

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Insta,InstaViewHolder> FBRA=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Insta,InstaViewHolder> (
                    Insta.class,
                    R.layout.insta_row,
                    InstaViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabase
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(InstaViewHolder viewHolder, Insta model, int position) {


                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                    viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());

                }
            };

            mInstaList.setAdapter(FBRA);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        public static class InstaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public InstaViewHolder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
                View mView=itemView;

            }

            public void setTitle(String title){
                TextView post_title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                post_title.setText(title);


            }
            public void setDesc(String desc){
                TextView post_desc=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
                post_desc.setText(desc);



            }

            public void setImage(Context ctx,String image){
                ImageView post_image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    //picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(id==R.id.addIcon){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,postActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        enter code here
            }
            else if (id==R.id.logout){
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `javascript` tag ?

Comment: this is due because you have declared not the same names and variable types in your POJO class as they are in your database structure in firebase, please post your POJO class and your database structure, post your Insta.class and a picture of your database in firebase